# Spark: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

Let's assume that we have the next simple command:

`./spark-sql --master spark://<ip:port> --driver-memory 2G --driver-cores 1 --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 10G`

**[Problem] On its execution Spark returns the next message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.                  hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager(SharedState.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$2(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:                  60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SessionCatalo                  g.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager(SessionCatalog.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.setCurrentDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:260)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.setCurrentNamespace(CatalogManager.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.SetCatalogAndNamespaceExec.$anonfun$run$2(SetCatalogA                  ndNamespaceExec.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.SetCatalogAndNamespaceExec.$anonfun$run$2$adapted(Set                  CatalogAndNamespaceExec.scala:36)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.SetCatalogAndNamespaceExec.run(SetCatalogAndNamespace                  Exec.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:3                  9)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:607)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:602)
        at org.gts.torchlight.sql.SchemaSql$.calculate(SchemaSql.scala:68)
        at org.gts.torchlight.sql.SchemaSql$.runTask(SchemaSql.scala:161)
        at org.gts.torchlight.sql.SchemaSql$.main(SchemaSql.scala:186)
        at org.gts.torchlight.sql.SchemaSql.main(SchemaSql.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:                  928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String                  ;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(R                  awLocalFileSystem.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFil                  eSystem.java:735)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSyst                  em.java:703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:711)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:586)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:548)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45                  )
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:2                  25)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:103)
        ... 48 more
```

I've set environmental variables on the following principles:

`export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-3.0.1`

`export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH`

`export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hadoop-2.7.2`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$HADOOP_HOME`

Spark cluster has the correct WebUI on 8080 port, HDFS healthcare and file browser is also listening.

**What should I check to avoid the problem?** I guess that `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `SPARK_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME` variables have correct values.

Comment: Please refer this - https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.0.1/  and see if you have downloaded spark built with Hadoop 2.7 ( which is the version of hadoop you have shown above)

Comment: Why not use latest Hadoop 3 version?